# Does "Signing" always mean encrypting a hash

Tags: signature

Does signing always involve encrypting a **hash** or can we call private key encryption of an **unhashed** message signing too?

Comment: I think this question is mainly asked and answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20093/1172). Please also note that it is a bad idea [to conflate signature generation with encryption using the private key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172). There are also questions / answers about generic attacks on (EC)DSA for direct signing on this site, but that's algorithm-specific.

Comment: Signing *never* means encrypting a hash. It's a *private key* operation, and in asymmetric systems encryption is *by definition* one of the two operations using the *public* key. At best you could say it sometimes involves something that's similar to decrypting a hash, though that'd still be inaccurate for RSA as used in practice (the "padding" is different).

Comment: Cryptographically speaking, signing always involves encrypting a hash of the message, not the message itself. This is because a hash function is a one-way function, meaning that it is computationally infeasible to reverse the hash and obtain the original message. This property is essential for ensuring the integrity of the signed message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need to compute message digest of a message first while signing it?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20093/why-do-we-need-to-compute-message-digest-of-a-message-first-while-signing-it)

Comment: @user1850484 The parts of your comment: "signing always involve encrypting a hash" - is incorrect in the use of terms; "because hash function is a one-way function" is irrelevant; "essential for ensuring the integrity" this is true, but your reasoning towards this conclusion is absent. Considering these, I suggest you delete your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Does signing always involve encrypting a **hash** ...

Do you think you can always decrypt it? In any/all digital signature algorithms?

- ECDSA: the signature is $(r,s)$, doesn't look like it.
- Dilithium/ML-DSA: the signature is $(z,h,c)$, doesn't look like it.
- SPHINCS+/SLH-DSA: the signature is a huge array of hash values, doesn't look like it.

Can you see the pattern now?