# RSA signature send signature with encrypted message?

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature

What is the correct procedure in sending an authenticated message, I've been researching and have been getting different answers, such as hash-then-sign [[1]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12768/why-hash-the-message-before-signing-it-with-rsa), [[2]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work)
, sign-then-encrypt [[3]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign) (but the link wasn't specific for RSA).

1. Do I send the hash-then-sign (with something like RSA-PSS PKCS#1) and attach it to the message or encrypted message?
2. Do I use sign-then-encrypt, I tried searching "sign then encrypt rsa", with no result on the scheme used, what cryptographic scheme would I use? Would I just use RSA-sign and RSA-encrypt?
3. Do I combine them and use hash-then-sign-then-encrypt and just send it as one, is there a cryptographic scheme for this?

Comment: Signing generally includes hashing to make it possible to sign larger messages. So there is in practice no difference between hash-then-sign and just sign.

Comment: The archetypal mistake would be to send in clear the signature of (the hash of) the message itself, for it would allow to check a guess of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The archetypal mistake would be to send in clear the signature of (the hash of) the message itself, for it would allow to check a guess of the message.

This leaves us with (at least) two general safe sketches (the first having advantages including allowing earlier elimination of bogus messages on the receiver side)

- encrypt, then sign the whole encrypted message;
- sign, then encrypt the whole signed message.

In both cases

- *encrypt* can be: draw a random key, then apply encryption padding, then apply the RSA exponentiation with a receiver's trusted public key, then append to that cryptogram the encryption of the input with a symmetric cryptosystem using said random key;
- *sign* can be: hash he input, then apply a signature padding, then apply the RSA exponentiation with a sender's private key, then append that signature to the input.

Comment: Say we have enough space and computing power, what would you say about s = sign(m), c = encrypt(m, s), sign(c)?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: yes, sending your (c,sign(c)) works; from an integrity perspective, that's belt and suspenders.

Comment: Just wanted to indicate this option. It lets you validate before decryption (less vulnerable against padding oracle attacks etc.) while still providing non-repudiation of the plaintext message in case you don't want to store the data encrypted.